# Why $\beta S$ is not a semigroup when $S$ is a (directed) partial semigroup?

Tags: set-theory, semigroups-and-monoids, infinite-combinatorics, stone-cech-compactification, topological-semigroups-and-monoids

Given a semigroup $(S, *)$ we extend the semigroup operation $*$ of $S$ to a operation $*$ on $\beta S$ (the set of ultrafilters on $S$) defined as
$$
    \mathcal{U} * \mathcal{V} = \left\{ A \subseteq S \colon (\mathcal{U}x)(\mathcal{V}y) \  x * y \in A \right\}.
$$

I'm using the ultrafilter quantifier, it's defined by
$$
    (\mathcal{U}x)\varphi(x) \quad \text{iff} \quad \{x \in S: \varphi(x)\} \in \mathcal{U}.
$$

It is a well known fact that $\beta S$ is the Stone–Čech compactification of $S$ (considering $S$ as a discrete space) with the topology generated by $\{ \overline{A} \colon A \subseteq S \}$ where $\overline{A} = \{ \mathcal{U} \in \beta S \colon A \in \mathcal{U} \}$.

It is also a well known fact that $(\beta S, *)$ is a compact semigroup (a compact Hausdorff space such that the map $\mathcal{U} \mapsto \mathcal{U} * \mathcal{V}$ is continuous for all $\mathcal{V}$).

A partial semigroup $(S, *)$ is directed (some authors call it *adequate*) if for all $\left\{x_0, \dots, x_n \right\} \subseteq S$ there exists $y \in S$ such that $y \neq x_{i}$ and $x_{i} * y$ is defined for all $i \in n$.

The extension above still works in the case of a directed partial semigroup $(S, *)$ but instead of $\beta S$ we use a portion of it denoted by $\gamma S$ (some authors denote it $\delta S$) where
$$
    \gamma S = \{ \mathcal{U} \in \beta S \colon (\forall s)(\{ t \in S \colon s * t \text{ is defined} \} \in \mathcal{U})\}
$$
and the (total) operation $*$ on $\gamma S$ is given by
$$
    \mathcal{U} * \mathcal{V} = \{A \subseteq S \colon (\mathcal{U} x)(\mathcal{V} y)(x * y \text { is defined} \wedge x * y \in A)\}.
$$

If $S$ is a directed partial semigroup, $\gamma S \neq \emptyset$, $\gamma S$ is closed in $\beta S$ and $(\gamma S, *)$ is a compact semigroup. My questions are

**Why $(\beta S, *)$ is not a semigroup?, Why do we need $\gamma S$?, $\beta S$ is already non-empty, do we really need $S$ to be directed?**

I've read a couple of different proofs of the fact that $(\gamma S, *)$ is a compact semigroup but none of those give an explanation to my question. One proof is basically identical to the proof that $\beta S$ is a semigroup (and it's expected since the operation is essentially the same), maybe there is a very subtle detail in the proof for $\gamma S$ that makes clear why $\beta S$ can't be a semigroup.

Comment: If $S$ is directed partial semigroup, how is $* \colon \beta S \times \beta S \to \beta S$ being defined here? If $*$ is a total binary operation on $S$, then we can define $\mathcal{U} * \mathcal{V}$ (but we would still have to worry about associativity).

Comment: $\mathcal U * \mathcal V$ seems to be perfectly well defined, for arbitrary $\mathcal U, \mathcal V \subseteq 2^S$, but only an element of $2^{2^S}$, not necessarily an ultrafilter.  For example, if $(S, *)$ is the partial semigroup with one element that cannot be multiplied by itself, and if $\mathcal U = \mathcal V$ is the unique ultrafilter, then $\mathcal U * \mathcal V$ is empty.

Comment: You should also be aware that what you are calling a compact semigroup is called a compact right (or sometimes left) semitopological semigroup.

Comment: My guess is that you cannot make this product always give an ultrafilter for principal ultrafilters unless S is a semigroup